# PHP:Variable in function not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to get dns records of a domain through dns_get_record() but the function doesn't seem to work when a variable is inserted..here's my code

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="host" placeholder="Enter IP or Domain"/>
     <select name="dns">
          <option value="DNS_A" selected="selected">A</option>
               ....
          <option value="DNS_ANY">ANY</option>
     </select>
</form>
<?php
$host=$_POST['host'];
$dns=$_POST['dns'];
$type=end(explode('_',$dns));
if ($host==""){
     exit();
}
echo "Results for $host $type record<br />";
$result = dns_get_record($host, $dns);
echo "Result = ";
print_r($result);
?>
```

but if i put

```
$result = dns_get_record($host, DNS_A);
```

instead of

```
$result = dns_get_record($host, $dns);
```

it works..help!

Comment: Learn what a constant is: http://php.net/constants

Comment: @ppeterka That *is* a constant for once, not a string! *Don't* quote it.

Comment: @deceze I didn't even think of that - I blindly (and dumbly) defaulted to the usual "not escaped string" issue I saw too many times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DNS_A` is a constant of value 1, while you are passing string "DNS_A", try by passing value of constant, using `$result = dns_get_record($host, constant($dns));`

Comment: it worked..but `$host` works even without passing a value of constant?

Answer (score 3):

This is because your POST returns a literal string: "DNS_A", if you prefer. This is ***NOT*** the same as DNS_A, which is a constant and most likely contains an integer.

You'll need a mapping table for this one. Or just pass the integer value straight off.